# Is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x\ln x)^n}{n!}$ a power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Why this is a power series?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x\ln x)^n}{n!}$$

The power series is like $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(x-a) ^n$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series). You already explained what a power series is. This is not a power series.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it is not a power series. Anyway it is a power series *in terms of $x\ln x$*.
Needless to say, it converges to $x^x$.

Comment: It is not a power series,but why it can integrate series term by term,l am doing an exercise,its answer say it is a power series,so it can integrate term by term.

Comment: It is not a power series. But there are things you can integrate term by term beyond power series.

Comment: @Rancho: it is a power series in terms of $x\ln x⁡$ (see my second sentence, first row). By the way, you should have asked the real question.
.

Answer (score 0):

[No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series). You already explained what a power series is. This is not a power series.